# Authenticating Apache against multiple ldap groups

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mod-auth-ldap

I'm using mod_authn_alias and mod_authnz_ldap against an Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
and I'm trying to configure ldap authentication against multiple domains.

My config is:

```
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap alpha>
  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=admin-alpha,CN=Users,DC=alpha,DC=local"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword "xxx"
  AuthLDAPURL "ldap://dc01.alpha.local/CN=Users,DC=alpha,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<AuthnProviderAlias ldap beta>
  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=admin-beta,CN=Users,DC=beta,DC=local"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword "xxx"
  AuthLDAPURL "ldap://dc01.beta.local/CN=Users,DC=test,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<Directory "/usr/local/nagios/addons/pnp/share">
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AuthName "Pnp Access"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthBasicProvider alpha beta
        AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
        #Important, otherwise "(9)Bad file descriptor: Could not open password file: (null)"
        AuthUserFile /dev/null
        #only members of this group can log in
        Require ldap-group CN=grp_nagiosadmins,DC=beta,DC=local
        Require ldap-group CN=grp_nagiosadmins,DC=alpha,DC=local
        ...
</Directory>
```

So if the user can't be authenticated to the alpha domain, it should failover to domain beta. However, no user from either domain can be authenticated with this config.

When I try to log in:

```
[Fri Mar 07 16:13:35 2014] [error] [client 10.100.13.30] access to /pnp failed, reason: require directives present and no Authoritative handler.
[Fri Mar 07 16:13:38 2014] [error] [client 10.100.13.30] access to /pnp failed, reason: require directives present and no Authoritative handler.
```

Why not put all my users in one domain? That's a long story and it ultimately wasn't my decision.

How do I configure this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem except that I was validating specific LDAP users rather than groups. The solution was to change the parameter of the **require** directive from **ldap-user** to just **user**. This is documented in the [comments section of the mod_authn_alias documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_alias.html#comments_section).

My understanding of this is that **mod_authn_alias** is not specific to LDAP. Its documentation says that it "allows extended authentication providers" and they don't necessarily have to be related to LDAP.

It's probably worth trying replacing your **require ldap-group** directive with just **require group** and be careful with the letter case.

Answer (score 1):

The error is about the

```
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
```

missing. that said, if you want to set multiple rules you must configure:

```
Satisfy any
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says: `require directives present and no Authoritative handler.`  So does it work if you set `AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on`?

Comment: From the apache documentation:


"Set to off if this module should let other authorization modules attempt to authorize the user, should authorization with this module fail. Control is only passed on to lower modules if there is no DN or rule that matches the supplied user name (as passed by the client)."

So if I set this to on the authentication won't failover to domain beta. I can only authenticate vs domain alpha and not beta if I set this directive to on.

Comment: The documentation says "other modules", not "other domains".  Have you tried it?